# codeigniter insert current time in database by controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

here is my controller code to insert data into database

```
$datau = array(
    'reg_no' => $firstname,
    'fee_type' => $productinfo,
    'transaction_id' => $txnid,
    'status' => '0'
);
$this->db->insert('payment_status', $datau);
$this->load->view('fail', $data);
```

this was working perfectly but when I try to add time like this:

```
$datau = array(
    'reg_no' => $firstname,
    'fee_type' => $productinfo,
    'transaction_id' => $txnid,
    'status' => '0',
    'time' => NOW()
);
$this->db->insert('payment_status', $datau);
$this->load->view('fail', $data);
```

it returns an error like

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\iiht\application\controllers\Status.php on line 47

Answer (score 2):

`now()` is a MySql function and will not work in php, use the `time()` function instead to store a Unix timestamp:

```
'time' => time();
```

Answer (score 1):

`NOW()` is `sql` function you should use

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

So your code should be

```
$datau = array(
    'reg_no' => $firstname,
    'fee_type' => $productinfo,
    'transaction_id' => $txnid,
    'status' => '0',
    'time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
);
$this->db->insert('payment_status', $datau);
$this->load->view('fail', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

use date function instead

```
'time' => date('H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
```

If it needs full date time then

```
'time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used following code for your problem :

Used this PHP date function as `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

```
$datau = array(
    'reg_no' => $firstname,
    'fee_type' => $productinfo,
    'transaction_id' => $txnid,
    'status' => '0',
    'time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
);
$this->db->insert('payment_status', $datau);
$this->load->view('fail', $data);
```

I hope it will help you.